# Spring Boot 2.6.6 upgrade to 3.0+ failing due Hibernate versions. What to do?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.5)

2023-05-01T16:44:20.101+02:00  INFO 44188 --- [  restartedMain] ---------------- using Java 19.0.2 with PID 44188 (C:\------------------------e)
2023-05-01T16:44:20.109+02:00  INFO 44188 --- [  restartedMain] ------------------: No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-05-01T16:44:20.188+02:00  INFO 44188 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-05-01T16:44:20.188+02:00  INFO 44188 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-05-01T16:44:21.893+02:00  INFO 44188 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-05-01T16:44:22.369+02:00  INFO 44188 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 469 ms. Found 46 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-05-01T16:44:23.140+02:00  INFO 44188 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-05-01T16:44:23.150+02:00  INFO 44188 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-05-01T16:44:23.150+02:00  INFO 44188 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.7]
2023-05-01T16:44:23.232+02:00  INFO 44188 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/api]    : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-05-01T16:44:23.233+02:00  INFO 44188 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3045 ms
2023-05-01T16:44:23.273+02:00  INFO 44188 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-05-01T16:44:23.560+02:00  INFO 44188 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@2c435f25
2023-05-01T16:44:23.562+02:00  INFO 44188 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-05-01T16:44:23.570+02:00  INFO 44188 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/txl'
2023-05-01T16:44:23.700+02:00  INFO 44188 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-05-01T16:44:23.762+02:00  INFO 44188 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final
2023-05-01T16:44:23.953+02:00  INFO 44188 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2023-05-01T16:44:24.102+02:00  INFO 44188 --- [  restartedMain] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2023-05-01T16:44:24.256+02:00 ERROR 44188 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'jwtRequestFilter' defined in file [C:\-------------------\security\utils\JwtRequestFilter.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'jwtUserDetailsService' defined in file [C:---------------------------\security\services\JwtUserDetailsService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in ------------------.repositories.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'
2023-05-01T16:44:24.277+02:00  INFO 44188 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-05-01T16:44:24.282+02:00  WARN 44188 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
2023-05-01T16:44:24.288+02:00  INFO 44188 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-05-01T16:44:24.295+02:00  INFO 44188 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2023-05-01T16:44:24.302+02:00  INFO 44188 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-05-01T16:44:24.322+02:00 ERROR 44188 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.BasicValueBinder.resolveJavaType(BasicValueBinder.java:1002)

The following method did not exist:

    'java.lang.reflect.Type org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager.toType(org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.XClass)'

The calling method's class, org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.BasicValueBinder, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/C:-------------/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/orm/hibernate-core/6.1.7.Final/hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/org/hibernate/cfg/annotations/BasicValueBinder.class

The called method's class, org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:----------/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.1.2.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar!/org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ReflectionManager.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager: file:/-----------------.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.1.2.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.BasicValueBinder and org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Spring Boot 2.6.6 upgrade to 3.0+ failing due Hibernate versions. What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you build with `maven` use the command `mvn dependency:tree` and inspect the results.

Probably from somewhere you have imported the `org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations`. This however according to Hibernate is already specified in `org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core` and they must be of some compatible version.

[image]

So the short answer is to correct the `org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations` to match with a compatible version of `org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core`.

As shown [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-core/6.1.7.Final) the compatible version for `org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations` is   **`6.0.6.Final`** when in use with `org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core` version `6.1.7.Final`.

Comment: Hi Panagiotis,
Thanks for answering. I now use the dependencies you mentioned above, but I am getting issues with my database. I've searched and tried the migration of hibernate, but it somehow keeps giving me the same errors.

2023-05-02T09:51:21.677+02:00 ERROR 21780 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.from.UnknownTableReferenceException: Unable to determine TableReference (-------) for

Comment: `--------.commandExceptions.{fk-target}`
2023-05-02T09:51:21.678+02:00 ERROR 21780 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'jwtRequestFilter' defined in file [C:--------security\utils\JwtRequestFilter.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1:

Comment: Error creating bean with name 'jwtUserDetailsService' defined in file [C:-----security\services\JwtUserDetailsService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.-----.repositories.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'

Comment: @EmalAjheer this should be a further issue that you face. I think you overcame the issue with version collisions, so please resolve the current thread and open another question with all details of the new problem.