# Spring Boot 2.6.6 upgrade to 3.0+ failing due database issues

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, updates

**Previous public question:**
**Spring Boot 2.6.6 upgrade to 3.0+ failing due Hibernate versions. What to do?**
[Spring Boot 2.6.6 upgrade to 3.0+ failing due Hibernate versions. What to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76147926/spring-boot-2-6-6-upgrade-to-3-0-failing-due-hibernate-versions-what-to-do)

**Problem which I am having now:**
The issue I am having now is also regarding the database. For some reason one (or more?) tables can not be determined.

Another error emerged, which is about injecting the UserRepository into the JwtUserDetailsService.

I came across some information on different types of websites, but non of the answers helped me solve my problem.

```
2023-05-02T09:51:21.677+02:00 ERROR 21780 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.from.UnknownTableReferenceException: Unable to determine TableReference (`position_type`) for `com.-------.----.{fk-target}`
2023-05-02T09:51:21.678+02:00 ERROR 21780 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.U-------tisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'jwtRequestFilter' defined in file [C:\-------\IdeaProjects\-------\target\classes\com\-------\-----\security\utils\JwtRequestFilter.class]: U-------tisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'jwtUserDetailsService' defined in file [C:\-------\IdeaProjects\-------\target\classes\com\-------\-------\security\services\JwtUserDetailsService.class]: U-------tisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.-------.-------.---- defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'
2023-05-02T09:51:21.695+02:00  INFO 21780 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-05-02T09:51:21.699+02:00  WARN 21780 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
.............

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-05-02T09:51:21.732+02:00 ERROR 21780 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:164) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:578) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at com.-------.-----.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:488) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:210) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:183) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.U-------tisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtRequestFilter' defined in file [C:\-------\IdeaProjects\-------\target\classes\com\-------\-------\security\utils\JwtRequestFilter.class]: U-------tisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'jwtUserDetailsService' defined in file [C:\-------\IdeaProjects\-------\target\classes\com\-------\-------\security\services\JwtUserDetailsService.class]: U-------tisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.-------.-------.---- defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:245) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1189) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:210) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:173) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:168) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:153) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:86) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:261) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:235) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:52) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4875) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:846) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:241) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:913) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:485) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.U-------tisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtUserDetailsService' defined in file [C:\-------\IdeaProjects\-------\target\classes\com\-------\-------\security\services\JwtUserDetailsService.class]: U-------tisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.-------.-------.---- defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:245) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1189) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    ... 57 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.-------.-------.---- defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1682) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    ... 71 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:691) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:515) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    ... 85 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.from.UnknownTableReferenceException: Unable to determine TableReference (`position_type`) for `com.-------.-------.-----.{fk-target}`
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    ... 97 common frames omitted
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.from.UnknownTableReferenceException: Unable to determine TableReference (`position_type`) for `com.-------.-----Exceptions.{fk-target}`
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    ... 104 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.from.UnknownTableReferenceException: Unable to determine TableReference (`position_type`) for `com.-------.------Exceptions.{fk-target}`
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.from.LazyTableGroup.resolveTableReference(LazyTableGroup.java:256) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.from.DelegatingTableGroup.resolveTableReference(DelegatingTableGroup.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.SimpleForeignKeyDescriptor.createDomainResult(SimpleForeignKeyDescriptor.java:248) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.SimpleForeignKeyDescriptor.createTargetDomainResult(SimpleForeignKeyDescriptor.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.PluralAttributeMappingImpl.createDelayedCollectionFetch(PluralAttributeMappingImpl.java:518) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.PluralAttributeMappingImpl.generateFetch(PluralAttributeMappingImpl.java:422) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.FetchParent.generateFetchableFetch(FetchParent.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder.lambda$createFetchableBiConsumer$6(LoaderSelectBuilder.java:860) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder.visitFetches(LoaderSelectBuilder.java:698) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSqlAstCreationState.visitFetches(LoaderSqlAstCreationState.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.AbstractFetchParent.afterInitialize(AbstractFetchParent.java:33) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityResultGraphNode.afterInitialize(AbstractEntityResultGraphNode.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntityFetchJoinedImpl.<init>(EntityFetchJoinedImpl.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ToOneAttributeMapping.lambda$generateFetch$0(ToOneAttributeMapping.java:1267) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ToOneAttributeMapping.withRegisteredAssociationKeys(ToOneAttributeMapping.java:1512) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ToOneAttributeMapping.generateFetch(ToOneAttributeMapping.java:1242) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ToOneAttributeMapping.generateFetch(ToOneAttributeMapping.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.FetchParent.generateFetchableFetch(FetchParent.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder.lambda$createFetchableBiConsumer$6(LoaderSelectBuilder.java:860) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder.visitFetches(LoaderSelectBuilder.java:698) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSqlAstCreationState.visitFetches(LoaderSqlAstCreationState.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.AbstractFetchParent.afterInitialize(AbstractFetchParent.java:33) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityResultGraphNode.afterInitialize(AbstractEntityResultGraphNode.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createDomainResult(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1300) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder.generateSelect(LoaderSelectBuilder.java:450) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder.createSelect(LoaderSelectBuilder.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.createLoadPlan(SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.prepare(SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.prepareLoader(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4376) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.postInstantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4368) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.finishInitialization(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:236) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.RuntimeMetamodelsImpl.finishInitialization(RuntimeMetamodelsImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:311) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:415) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1423) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    ... 108 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating hibernate-core to 6.2.0 fixed the issue

Comment: I doubt that this is the solution, but rather fixing the sympom. You should use `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` as a dependency and not individual hibernate dependencies. If you have you are fighting the dependency management done by Spring Boot. If you really want to override the version specify the `hibernate.version` property but don't include dependencies.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum I actually didn't change anything else but the hibernate-core version. That's when the project started running as normal again. But thanks for the advice on the individual hibernate dependencies.

Comment: i did like you but wont works :  
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>6.2.0</version>
  </dependency>
Could not find artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-core:pom:6.2.0 in central